# How to create dynamic NestJS modules for Sequelize models?

Tags: nestjs, sequelize-typescript

I have a number of Sequelize models in my NestJS service. I have a module for each of them with controllers. I want to create a dynamic module, that would provide a service which will execute queries on these models. I would use the service's methods in the controllers.
I have a solution that is working as expected, but I'm not sure if it's a good implementation.

This is my dynamic module:

```
export type RelationModuleOptions = {
  model: typeof Model
}

@Module({})
export class RelationModule {
  static register(options: RelationModuleOptions): DynamicModule {
    return {
      module: RelationModule,
      providers: [
        {
          provide: 'RELATION_MODEL',
          useValue: options
        },
        RelationService
      ],
      exports: [RelationService]
    }
  }
}
```

And this is the service it exports:

```
@Injectable()
export class RelationService {
  private readonly model: any;
  constructor(
    @Inject('RELATION_MODEL') options: RelationModuleOptions,
  ) {
    this.model = options.model
  }

  async findMany(): Promise<any> {
    return await this.model.findAll();
  }

  async findOne(relationId: number): Promise<any> {
    return await this.model.findOne() 
  }

}
```

My problem with the above, is that I have to type the module that is passed in the options object as `typeof Model`, otherwise I get error when I'm trying to pass in a `Model` instance:
`Type 'typeof Subtopic' is missing the following properties from type 'Model<any, any>': $add, $set, $get, $count, and 23 more.`

So I have to type the `model` property of the service as `any`, otherwise I got errors when trying to call `findAll` or `findOne` methods.

I import `Model` from sequelize-typescript.

How can I type this correctly? Or is there a better way of implementing this?